# WHat is most efficient way to insert timestamp into timestamp with CQL

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am able to insert a timestamp from c# CQL with this commeand:

```
INSERT INTO tick_store."MY_Data"
("SeqNum", "utcDT")
VALUES(0, '2014-08-22T11:00:15.636')
```

And I format utcDT with .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
BUT I understand I could send "ticks" instead.

Would that be more efficient, or do I need to adjust ticks to a specific Cassandra epoch?

Answer (score 0):

The expected C# type for a CQL timestamp is `DateTimeOffset`:

```
var statement = new SimpleStatement(
  "INSERT INTO table1 (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)", id, DateTimeOffset.Now)
session.Execute(statement);
```

You should use query markers (`?`) and pass the values as arguments instead of stringifying those yourself.